# One computer is getting slower internet speeds on the same wired connection

Tags: networking, internet-connection, wired-networking

So two computers, only about a year difference in age are getting significantly different speeds using the same wired connection.  One computer gets between 80-100 mbps download, the other gets 1-30 mbps download. The slower computer is clean of malware (I used Malware Bytes).   The problem is not the cable because I used the same cable for these tests.

The slower computer is an HP ENVY m6-1105dx Notebook PC, running Windows 8
The faster computer is a Dell Lattitude E6430, running Windows 7.

UPDATE: When I rebooted in Safe Mode, my connection was about twice as fast, using speedof.me as a benchmark.

Comment: What network cards does each machine have? The faster machine may have a better network card.

Comment: The slower one has a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485. I'm not sure the faster one, don't have access to it right now.

Comment: What OS?, and can you amend answer, instead of writing amendments in comments. I don't want to read a page of comments to know what the question is.

Comment: This will be difficult to answer because so many things can be different between the two PCs. NIC, Windows settings, bus speeds, memory, etc. If the PCs were identical, then it would be easier to narrow down.

Comment: Test the slower computer in [Safe Mode with Netowrking](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode) -- Is it any faster/different?

Comment: How are you benchmarking the download speed?

Comment: Rebooting in Safe Mode nearly doubled my speed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking at the following applicable to the slower machine:

1. Is the slower system properly patched?
2. Have you tried a different network card?
3. Have you tried using a different switch/router port?
4. Are you sure that the network parameters on the computer are properly configured?  I'd suggest Auto negogation.
5. Is the switch port configured properly? Generally use Auto unless there are hardware problems.
6. You have not answered the question but what is the operating system and version being used?
7. The wire between where you plug-in and the switch port may problematic.
8. Are you sure that the slower computer is not having any other hardware problem?
9. Are you sure that the older machine is not having a problem with its job mix, causing low throughput?

Well, these are a few of my initial suggestions.

Comment: Is the slower computer slower in other specs as well? Is the slower computer cheaper stock? Is there a dedicated network card in both computers?